# Next.js server automatically ends after a few seconds of running "npm run dev"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, react-fullstack

i am running next.js for the first time, copied the installation script form the official page

```
npx create-next-app@latest hello-word
```

but after installation and running "npm run dev " or "yarn dev, it runs the server on port 3000, then after few second just kills the server

[image: 1]

i have tried to run lesser versions that ain't next13 but i got same issue

Answer (score 0):

Hi had the same problem when using nextjs 13.x
I resolved by re-installing the node version. And I notice that somehow my node architecture was 32 instead of 64. So worth to check your:

- Node architecture
- Node version

Answer (score 0):

My solution was way simpler than I thought the problem was, I deleted the node packages folder and reinstalled them again, 'npm install'. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the version of your Node by running "node -v" in the terminal. If it is not the latest (you can find the latest on the node's official website), upgrade it. You can use Chocolatey, nvm, or any other method of your choice. After the upgrade to the latest version, restart your PC and confirm that the version upgrade was done.
Then open your project and run "npn run dev" again.
This worked for me and I even made a video about the solution [here](https://youtu.be/hALUBt7ue28)

Comment: Didn't work:  
`node -v`
gives `v21.4.0`  but 

 `next dev` gives  `- ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000`
`- info Loaded env from /path/.env
`

Then stops immediately, no error whatsover.